# Nome de um Role com acento no banco de dados Identity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, identity

Surgiu a necessidade de criar um `Role` com acento na tabela de `Roles` do `Identity` no banco de dados: "Técnico".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é se isso pode gerar problemas posteriores, talvez na hora de verificar algo do tipo `User.IsInRole("Técnico")` ou se o banco de dados pode se perder, não sei...

Gostaria de saber se posso criar sem medo de enfrentar problemas futuros e se é recomendado usar acentos para esse tipo de informação ou manter sem acentuação mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe um problema `técnico` em utilizar acentos, ou até mesmo espaços. Até por que o que é comparado não é o `Name` e sim o `NormalizedName`,  este por definição deve permitir a comparação com caracteres especiais.: [`Unicode® Standard Annex #15`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)

Vamos dá uma olhada no código fonte `Identity`:

[**RoleStore.cs**](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/855f7532aeaba3fa65e6ea2502e6b45dca50bab1/src/EF/RoleStore.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the role who has the specified normalized name as an asynchronous operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="normalizedName">The normalized role name to look for.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> used to propagate notifications that the operation should be canceled.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task{TResult}"/> that result of the look up.</returns>
    public virtual Task<TRole> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        return Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.NormalizedName == normalizedName, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Note, que a propriedade que é utilizada para encontrar uma Role é a `NormalizedName`

Agora vamos olhar o método que você deve está utilizando para criar um `Role`:

[**RoleManager.cs**](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/a273e349eea2be3a40b16e6947b2deab95f4b5b2/src/Core/RoleManager.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the specified <paramref name="role"/> in the persistence store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="role">The role to create.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TRole role)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (role == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));
        }
        var result = await ValidateRoleAsync(role);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        await UpdateNormalizedRoleNameAsync(role);
        result = await Store.CreateAsync(role, CancellationToken);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the normalized name for the specified <paramref name="role"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="role">The role whose normalized name needs to be updated.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual async Task UpdateNormalizedRoleNameAsync(TRole role)
    {
        var name = await GetRoleNameAsync(role);
        await Store.SetNormalizedRoleNameAsync(role, NormalizeKey(name), CancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a normalized representation of the specified <paramref name="key"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The value to normalize.</param>
    /// <returns>A normalized representation of the specified <paramref name="key"/>.</returns>
    public virtual string NormalizeKey(string key)
    {
        return (KeyNormalizer == null) ? key : KeyNormalizer.Normalize(key);
    }
```

[**LookupNormalizer.cs**](https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/blob/master/src/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/LookupNormalizer.cs)

```
    public class LookupNormalizer : ILookupNormalizer
    {
        public string Normalize(string key)
        {
            return key.Normalize().ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muito interessante, +1, mas um adendo, e nas versões anteriores ao `.Net Core` que não tinha o campo `NormalizedName`!?

Comment: @Barbetta sem realizar alguns testes, ou até mesmo sem olhar o código fonte do mesmo, é difícil de te dá uma resposta. Mas acredito que também deva funcionar (EF6 deve ser maduro suficiente para saber em que situação deve normalizar o nome da Role antes de realizar a comparação).

Comment: fiz um teste rápido aqui com acentos e espaços e foi normal ;)